# Python base deployment techniques/package libraries for different environment like development, production or staging

Tags: python, django, deployment, configuration, settings

I am familiar with environment settings for Node.js using npm packages like ["settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/settings)". This package allowed me to import different environment settings based on what the NODE_ENV variable is set to.

I've been searching for something similar for python but most of the environments settings tutorial is catered towards python developed on Django framework.

The only one that I found close to what I want is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yconf

However the config settings for different environment should not be limited to just development, production and staging. Was wondering if anyone can suggest similar alternatives or maybe even argue whether using Django framework is relevant in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `virtualenv` is  what you needed. Click [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for more info.

Comment: To add to @shellbye entirely correct suggestion: if you really want separate environments, you may use a visualization tool like virtualbox or vmware, and build separate (virtual) machines for each environment. More work than it's worth, though.